# Check if string contains 10 digit number but space after each digit using php

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

Suppose

```
$str = "hi hello 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 ok"
```

so the match found. I have tried with regex like

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9 ]{20}/', $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
```

but it matches others also

Comment: What do you mean with 'it matches others also'?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following pattern:

```
\b[0-9](?: [0-9]){9}\b
```

Your updated code:

```
$str = "hi hello 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 ok";
preg_match_all('/\b[0-9](?: [0-9]){9}\b/', $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches[0][0]);

Array ( [0] => 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 [1] => 9 )
```

The reason for placing the word boundaries (`\b`) around both sides of the pattern is to prevent a false match along the lines of the following

```
10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 012
```

That is, we need to make sure that the first and final digits are in fact single digits by themselves, and not parts of larger numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

**Regex :**

```
(?:[0-9][ ]){10}
```

**Verify through regex101 :**

[image]

Comment: Your pattern asserts a trailing space after the 10th digit, and so `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0` would fail, when in fact it should match.

Answer (score 0):

your regex is matching space before the first number, that is the problem

```
[0-9 ]{20}
```

To correct it by starting with `[0-9]` you enforce the first match to be a number and adjust a space followed by a number(`[ ][0-9]`) 9 times.

```
[0-9](?:[ ][0-9]){9}
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/UflKLb/1)

Comment: The OP is trying to match _ten_ digits, not twenty digits.

Comment: look the input string has space and numbers, so the `[0-9][0-9 ]{19}` should check `10` digits if the numbers are single digits, ofcourse the OP did not mention the numbers are multiple digits.

Comment: Your regex is matching, for example, 1 digit followed by 19 spaces!

Comment: @Toto yes, but the OP is saying the input sting is number followed by space... if that is the case, this regex applies. i just was fixing his regex

Comment: They want to **check** if the string contains 10 digits + spaces. Your regex matches many strings that don't contain 10 digits.